# Using std::accumulate to add floats with best precision

Tags: c++, stl

I want to accumulate the total into a double rather than a float.

```
vector<float> v;
....
double total  = std::accumulate(v.begin(),
                                v.end(),
                                static_cast<double>(0.0));
//This compiles but I am not sure it is doing what I want
```

...

```
double total_ = std::accumulate<double>(v.begin(),
                                        v.end(),
                                        static_cast<double>(0.0)
                                       );

// This doesnt compile, which leads me to believe the first accumulate
// is coercing the double(0.0) back to float.
```

Is there an STL idiomatic and succinct way to write

```
double total = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
  total += v[i];
}
```

using nothing more than the standard library.

I know this is not sufficient for maintaining precision.

Comment: The interface of `std::accumulate` indeed is clumsy. I've got my own version, where `accumulate<double>(v.begin(), v.end())` just works. (As does `accumulate(v.begin(), v.end())`, which just defaults to the element type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accumulation type used in [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is deduced from the type of the third argument. The literal `0.0` is a `double`, so this performs the accumulation using `double`, without need for explicit casts:

```
double total  = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0);
```

It is the equivalent of

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (f : v) sum += f;
```

Comment: Thats what I think, and that was my first code snippet, could you point me to something authoritative. The reason I am doubting my solution is that the compiler is rejecting my second code snippet, although that does not prove anything.

Comment: @san Look at the first overload in the reference linked above. Template deduction is used to deduce the type of the iterators as well as the accumulator.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible implementation from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```
template<class InputIt, class T>
T accumulate(InputIt first, InputIt last, T init)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        init = init + *first;
    }
    return init;
}
```

The type of the return value is decided by the 3rd argument, which has nothing to do with other two arguments, so the first accumulate should be OK.

And maybe you can have a test on it to confirm it can or not maintain the precision.

Comment: Note that is just an example implementation. The standard does not mandate *how* exactly it is implemented, just how it has to behave.

Comment: Are you sure that is how it is implemented ? I think that was just an illustrative example. Thanks for the answer though,I have upvoted your answer. Given that juanchopanza replied first, I am accepting his, hope you dont mind.